# Rock, Paper, Scissors using onclick function to populate player results

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm currently working through a prep course for a bootcamp and the last assignment is to put some basic JavaScript functions into a rock, paper, scissors game. I'm stuck trying to finish this onclick function.

What is the best way to populate the users choice when they click the buttons?

I've currently got my choices defined and set-up in an array. So, I guess I'm trying to get the defined choices to equal the buttons pushed. If I'm thinking correctly I want ex: choices[1] to also be my "Papyrus" button. I've attempted const () =, but I get a no "initializer" warning.

UPDATED ONCLICK FUNCTION. Everywhere I looked and on my lessons it had function(e) with e.target.id and I changed the querySelector to querySelectorAll to grab all the buttons. But still not seeing the console.log output nor seeing the compareChoice results on the screen.

```
const firstChoice = "Lapis";
const secondChoice = "Papyrus";
const thirdChoice = "Scalpellus";
const choices = ['Lapis', 'Payrus', 'Scalpellus'];

player.currentChoice = document.querySelectorAll('button').onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id); 
}
 //Example of on of the choice outcomes
else if(computer.currentChoice === choices[0]){
    if(player.currentChoice === choices[1]){
      displayResults("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }else{
      displayResults("The computer loses! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I can see from your code is that you are not defining your `onclick` callback correctly.

You should use the `addEventListener` function instead, with the first parameter being the event you want to listen to ( `"click"` in your case ) and the second being your callback.

Note that the callback can take a parameter, which is the event.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // do something once the button is clicked. 
});
```

A callback is just a function that will be executed at some point. And since you seams to be using the "Return value" of the callback in the rest of the code, it is not going to be executed properly. Take the example bellow.

```js
const myButton = document.querySelector('#button');

let myVariable;
// proper way to define an event listener.
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    myVariable = "Some string";
});

console.log(myVariable); // will always be undefined.
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me !</button>
```

Notice how the console always output `undefined` when you run the code ?

This is because, the callback and the rest of the code are not executed at the same time. Even though the `console.log` part comes after the callback, it is run at with the rest of the code, not when the callback is trigger. Only the code in the callback will be run when the event we listen to is triggered.

That being said, you can define variable outside the callback and use it inside. This could be useful to keep track of what each player has chosed.

With that in mind, you need to move the logic that check whether or not the player has won, in your callback.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if(player.currentChoice === choices[1]){
    // player wins
    } else {
     // computer wins.
    }
});
```

As for the *populate the users choice* part, you don't really need an external variable. You can simply listen to the click and get the player's choice using the `event.target.id` like you did previously. Then compare that with a predefined *computer move*.

Here is a somewhat working example.

```js
const choices = ['Lapis', 'Payrus', 'Scalpellus'];

const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// we register the listener on the `click` event, for each buttons.
for(let i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i ++) {

  allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // we retrieve the player's choice from the id of the clicked button.
    const playerChoice = event.target.id;

    // we get a random id for the computer's move.
    const randomChoiceId = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);

    const computerChoice = choices[randomChoiceId];
    
    // we check if the player wins. 
    // I don't know the logic and comparing each element might
    // not be the more efficient way to achieve this. But it works for now.
    if(playerChoice === "Lapis" && computerChoice === "Payrus") {
      console.log('Player Wins ! ');
    } else {
      console.log('Computer wins... ');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="Lapis">Lapis</button>
<button id="Payrus">Payrus</button>
<button id="Scalpellus">Scalpellus</button>
```

Hopefully, this brief overview of callback was clear enough to help you go forward in your project. Good luck !

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to get the "displayResults" string in the () to populate based on what the user selects. So, if I click "Payrus" and the computer chooses "Lapis" it will populate the the player has won with that text below the button. Just trying to figure what in your code triggered losing the function.

Comment: I can now see the text I added to the DOM and when I follow the console I can see clicking the buttons is working. But I don't see any match results from the "displayResults" string. Pretty much the computer isn't playing along.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have `player` Obj and multiple buttons where user can pick from

```js
let player = {
        currentChoice: ''
    },
    computer = {
        computerSelection: ['Lapis', 'Payrus', 'Scalpellus'],
        currentChoice: ''
    };

const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', getUserSelection);
}


function compare() {
    let playerChoice = player.currentChoice,
        computerChoice = computer.currentChoice,
        outcome = '';

    if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
        outcome = 'draw';
    } else if (playerChoice === 'Lapis' && computerChoice === 'Scalpellus' || (playerChoice === 'Papyrus' && computerChoice === 'Lapis') || (playerChoice === 'Scalpellus' && computerChoice === 'Papyrus')) {
        outcome = 'You win';
    } else {
        outcome = 'You lose'
    }
    displayResults(outcome)
    displayResults(`You picked ${playerChoice}`)
    displayResults(`Computer picked ${computerChoice}`)
}

function getUserSelection(e) {
    player.currentChoice = this.id;
    // From here trigger a function that compares
    // User slection against computers random selection
    startTheFight();

}

function setComputerChoice() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (computer.computerSelection.length - 1)) + 1;
    computer.currentChoice = computer.computerSelection[random];
}

function startTheFight() {
    // Get a random selection
    setComputerChoice();
    compare();


}

function displayResults(result) {
    const resultText = document.createElement('p');
    resultText.innerText = result;
    document.body.appendChild(resultText);
}
```

```html
<button id="Lapis">
    Lapis
</button>
<button id="Papyrus">
    Papyrus
</button>
<button id="Scalpellus">
    Scalpellus
</button>
```

Edit:In your case, can show the result ultimatium like in the example

Comment: Thank you! You the buttons to work, but when I changed that I can't get the results of match to populate below' This is my current code to get results:                                
  '''function displayResults(result){ 
  const resultText = document.createElement('p');
  resultText.innerText = result;
  document.body.appendChild(resultText);
}'''

Comment: @SamanthaBlum, notice that `player.currentChoice` is lowerCase, in this case for example you're matching `lapis === Lapis`.